# searchform.php override not working

Tags: theme-development, widgets, forms, sidebar

I'm taking a Udemy class to learn how to make Wordpress plugins and themes. The video I'm on is having me override the default search widget with a custom one via searchform.php. From what I've gathered, this file should automatically be loaded with the rest of the theme as long as I have followed these steps:

/theme_dir/functions.php

```
/* Some other code */
include ( get_theme_file_path('/includes/widgets.php') );
add_action("widgets_init", 'ju_widgets');
```

/theme_dir/includes/widgets.php

```
function ju_widgets() {
    register_sidebar([
        'name'          => __('My First Theme Sidebar', 'udemy'),
        'id'            => 'ju_sidebar',
        'description'   => __('Sidebar for the theme Udemy', 'udemy'),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget clearfix %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4>',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
    ]);
}
```

/theme_dir/sidebar.php

```
<div class="sidebar nobottommargin col_last">
    <div class="sidebar-widgets-wrap">
        <?php
            if (is_active_sidebar('ju_sidebar')) {
                dynamic_sidebar('ju_sidebar');
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

/theme_dir/searchform.php

```
<?php $unique_id = esc_attr( uniqid( 'search-form-' ) ); ?>

<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form"
      action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" id="<?php echo $unique_id; ?>"
               class="form-control" name="s"
               value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>"
               placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search', 'udemy' ); ?>"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

/theme_dir/index.php

```
<!-- some theme html -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<!-- other theme html -->
```

No matter what I change in the searchform.php file, it doesn't replace the default search widget.

Comment: searchform.php is rendered via `get_search_form` if the widget doesn't use `get_search_form` and instead has its own separate search-form it wouldn't work. 

How old is the course you're studying & does it take into account that widgets have recently been replaced by gutenberg blocks?

Comment: Gutenberg blocks are further in the course. I guess the guy didn't bother to take out this lesson. Unless this course redeems its self between now and the end i'm giving it a 1 star. What a waste of a whole day trying to figure out what I did wrong. Except it wasn't me in the first place. From what I gathered so far the teacher is an idiot. This is coming from a seasoned Laravel dev, so I think I have a "cred" to judge him at this point.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Happy to help, welcome to [WordPress.StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This way of working with widgets is outdated and I should be using Gutenberg blocks. Moral of the story, be careful when buying courses from Udemy, they may just be useless.

Comment: Well more out-of-date than useless. You should probably pass that on as feedback to Udemy.

Comment: True, I'll shoot him a message and see what he says.

Answer (score 1):

The person who posted this question is probably taking this Udemy course because I recognize the code:
[Complete WordPress Developer Course - Plugins & Themes](https://www.udemy.com/course/wordpress-development-create-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/)

I'm also taking the course and here's how I made the **searchform.php** template file work in my Gutenberg WordPress site:

1. Install the [Disable Gutenberg plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/) and inside the settings (like **localhost/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=disable-gutenberg**) next to the **Classic Widgets** heading check the **Disable Block Widgets and enable Classic Widgets** checkbox and click **Save Changes**.
2. Go back to the Widgets Admin page (like **localhost/wp-admin/widgets.php**) and remove the existing widgets (which will probably be Gutenberg blocks) and add the available classic WordPress widgets.

Finally, the Udemy course above does include sections on Gutenberg (**Gutenberg Prerequisites**, **Gutenberg Development**, etc.) so I believe the course is still worth taking. And you get into the Gutenberg sections of the course you can disable or uninstall the [Disable Gutenberg plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/) and Gutenberg features will be restored.